# Why is the dive on Another Day missing?

Tags: neo-the-world-ends-with-you

I have completed the main story of NEO: TWEWY and am attempting to complete the game's final dive mission on Another Day. According to [this guide](https://game8.co/games/NEO-TWEWY/archives/339597), (which contains a late-game spoiler), the final dive should be located in Dogenzaka. However, when I go there, the NPC for the final dive isn't present.

How do I find the NPC for the final dive on Another Day? Why can't I see them in Dogenzaka?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dive on Another Day will only appear in Dogenzaka after you've signed up for the Reaper's Romp near Hachiko. This also applies to the Time Trial challenge.